# how to copy content of a file to specific line in another file in linux

Tags: linux, shell, copy

I want to copy content of a file to the specific line of another file.

For example, I want to copy :

```
echo "some text file" >> file.txt
```

but i want to copy `some text file` to line 5 of file.txt.

Comment: The contents of a file, or just a given string?

Answer (score 1):

Replace line number 5

```
sed '5s/.*/This is line 5/' file
```

Insert a string before line 5

```
sed  '5i This is Line 4' file
```

Append a string after line 5

```
sed  '5a This is Line 6' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed -i '4a\some text file' file.txt
```

copy "some text file" to line 5 of file.txt.

I test this is ok, you can try this code.